# In my html input field, the cursor is set into the middle. How can I set my cursor to the right position?

Tags: html, css, windows

I'm developing my form only just using HTML and CSS. I have created the input fields with the rounded border. I need to set my cursor to the beginning of the input field.

```
<input type="text" id="itemName" name="itemName" 
  style="border-radius: 4px; padding: 6px 236px;" 
  wrap="physical">
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you show your code as well. Also the IDE/ text editor you use doesn't matter when it comes to implementations. IDEs only assist and speed up  your development process.

Comment: <input type="text" id="itemName" name="itemName" style="border-radius: 4px; padding: 6px 236px;" wrap="physical">

Answer (score 3):

To set cursor to right side use "direction" rule of CSS

```
input{
    direction: rtl;    
}
```

To set offset we may use "text-indent" rule

```
input{
    direction: rtl; 
    text-indent: 10px; // based on your border radius and input size you may change it
}
```

Comment: I need to set my cursor to the left corner of the input field.

Comment: The direction property is for defining what order and direction words/text should flow from for the browser. (As in languages that read/write right-to-left.) If you want to change the layout/alignment of a subset of text (like input field text/cursors), the text-alignment property is the correct way to go.

Comment: What is the purpose of using padding of 236px.

Comment: It's for align the input field.

Comment: Do you have graphical layout of what you are trying to achieve?
Possibly with different states of input.
For example : https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMuKS.png

Answer (score 1):

If you want all of the text/words on your site to flow right-to-left (as in for languages not written left-to-right), then use the direction CSS property.

However if you just want to change the cursor placement in your input fields, you'll want to use the text-align property:

```
input {
  text-align: left;
}
```

If it helps I threw together a code example: https://codepen.io/code-and-pixels/pen/gJNGaL